# changing the price of an exchange (in ecoinvent) with brightway?

Tags: brightway

I want to add a new exchange (by-product) to an existing activity that for which I would need to add a price property, in order to have the possibility of having an economic allocation between the reference product and the by-product.

I looked at the attributes of the exchanges with

```
exc.as_dict()
```

but this is not a field I could find anywhere.

Is it possible to alter the price of an exchange in the ecoinvent database with brightway2? (in order to have impact the economic allocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prices have been available as exchange properties as of [33d9d67](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/commit/33d9d674bb351e1fe0c971438e57d7af1ea2bac6), released in 0.8.1 on February 25, 2021:

```
>>> import bw2data as bd
>>> a = bd.Database("ecoinvent 3.7.1 cutoff").random()
>>> for exc in a.technosphere():
>>>     print(exc['properties'])['price']
{
    'amount': 0.014, 
    'unit': 'EUR2005', 
    'comment': 'Calculated value based on data from United Nations Commodity Trade Statistics Database (comtrade.un.org). UN comtrade category: 252100 Limestone materials for manufacture of lime or cement. Year 2005. Using exchange rate of 1EURO = 1.209 USD. Average of price of import into 5 main markets (EU, US, JP, IN and CN).'
}
```

Be sure to save the exchange object afterwards if you want you changes to persist.

However, the answer of Nabla is correct, changing the price won't change the allocation. The `multifunctional` library wants to work on this, but it isn't simple. For example, there are many economic allocation methods in ecoinvent.

Luckily, allocation is not that difficult. I would recommend using helper functions from [wurst](https://github.com/polca/wurst) (e.g. finding and copying exchanges). And implementing allocation is a good first exercise to learning how to use Brightway on a deeper level.

Comment: Thank you, it seems I ended up finding a way with SimaPro to do what I need, but I will try to play with this to get more into the depth of bw soon

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware price data is not yet parsed from the ecospold files. Brightway uses the version of ecoinvent after multifunctionality has been solved (by ecoinvent). So:

1. the prices are not yet there.
2. the algorithms to recalculate ecoinvent changing the prices aren't there either. The Ocelot project was an attempt but its not easy.

You may want to have a look to https://github.com/brightway-lca/multifunctional